# Updating a global JS variable with Jquery and return that value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global

I need to write a function where I can set a global variable in plain js, update it's value with jQuery function and then assign that value that was updated via jQuery function into a normal javasciprt variable.

Here is the code example:

```
var foo; // global variable in plain js
var bar; // second global variable
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 

   // jquery function that updates the variable
   foo = 'updated by jquery' 

 });

bar = foo;

console.log(bar); // console should read 'updated by jquery' but it says undefined
```

Comment: `foo` will be updated when the DOM is loaded, since it is in the document.ready() function.  However, the `console.log` will execute right away before the page is loaded

Comment: How can i make this work? because I need to pass the change that jquery made and update the global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are updating the `foo` only on `ready event` but you are tying to log before ready fires

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
// jquery function that updates the variable
  foo = 'updated by jquery';
  console.log(foo);
});
```

Comment: this does not solve my issue because i am trying to update the global variable and i need that change to be available after the function runs.

Comment: @n00b3, assign some default value initially. like `var foo='yes';`

Comment: @n00b3 it is available after the function runs. This issue is that the function doesn't run until jQuery's `DOMReady` event fires. If you need it sooner, unwrap it from the `DOMReady` or delay the functions that require the variable until the `DOMReady` event has fired.

Answer (score 2):

It won't set the value to 'updated by jquery', because that update will take place when the document is ready, whereas your `console.log(foo)` is a part of global which will occur previously in sequence than document ready function call.

So, essentially,

```
var foo; // #1
$(function ($) { 
  foo = 'updated by jquery';
  console.log(foo); // output : updated by jquery //#3
});

console.log(foo); // output : undefined //#2
```

And the order of execution is #1, #2, #3

So, if you need the updated value, you'll need to access it at point #3 inside document .ready after it has been changed. Or you can raise/trigger an event once the value has been changed using Jquery Events like -

```
foo='updated';
var event = jQuery.Event( "myEvent" );
$('body').trigger(event);

// The following can now be outside of document ready
$('body').on('myEvent',function(){
   // Access updated foo value here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Yes, i understand this how can i change this so i get a return value that is updated by the function? the function don't need to run on document.ready

Comment: You can do that using events, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually should work correctly. But if we use the comments as markers in order (so #2 = "//jquery function that updates the variable"), keep in mind it'll run in the order [#1, #3, #2] because the ready() function will run after the others when the document is ready.

As long as any code that needs foo is running *after* your ready function, it should read it correctly.

Comment: how to i change this code so that i get the updated value after the function runs?

Comment: ...You don't have to change it. You DO get the updated value after the function runs. But the function is *running* later than you think it is; that middle section only runs after the document is ready, but the outside code block (both above and below the function) will execute before that. One alternative is to set the variable to its value outside of that function, if you need its value available straight away.